# Cannot convert list of dto to list of dynamic

Tags: c#

How can I make this to work? It giving me an error cannot `implicitly convert`. I have lots of DTO on my WebApp and I need a placeholder variable.

NOTE: This is not the actual code on my WebApp, this is just the same idea on what I want to do.

```
public class DTO1
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class DTO2
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class DTO1Service
{
    public static List<DTO1> GetListOfDTO1()
    {
        return new List<DTO1>
        {
            new DTO1 { Id = 1, Name = "DTO 1" },
            new DTO1 { Id = 2, Name = "DTO 2" }
        };
    }
}

public class DTO2Service
{
    public static List<DTO2> GetListOfDTO2()
    {
        return new List<DTO2>
        {
            new DTO2 { Id = 1, Name = "DTO 1" },
            new DTO2 { Id = 2, Name = "DTO 2" }
        };
    }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var entities = new List<dynamic>();

        var serviceType = Console.ReadLine();

        if(serviceType == "1")
            entities = (dynamic)DTO1Service.GetListOfDTO1();
        else if (serviceType == "2")
            entities = (dynamic)DTO2Service.GetListOfDTO2();

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: any example on which part you get the error..? i'm not sure about the `DTO` part.. but you can't *cast* `DT01` to `DT02`.. only able to cast to its superclass..

Comment: on the part `entities = (dynamic)DTO01Service.GetListOfDTO01();`

Comment: ah i see, because you're trying to cast the list itself instead of the list members..

Comment: I would suggest to stay away from dynamic, unless you absolutely need it and any other solution is very painful, as in MS Office libraries. Other cases you will lose compile type checking. If you give us a clear definition of what you want to do, we may be of help

Comment: @EmrahSüngü well, im trying to make a helper class for all my DTO. I was building an ecommerce project and i want to make a helper methods to check for duplicate name and seo url.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Cast` method to explicitly cast it to `dynamic`, like so:

```
if(serviceType == "1")
        entities = DTO1Service.GetListOfDTO1().Cast<dynamic>().ToList();
else if (serviceType == "2")
        entities = DTO2Service.GetListOfDTO2().Cast<dynamic>().ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You are casting it wrong. You are trying to assign a `dynamic` to a `List<dynamic>` instead of the list members

You can either create a new instance and pass the values in

```
if(serviceType == "1")
    entities = new List<dynamic>(DTO1Service.GetListOfDTO1());
else if (serviceType == "2")
    entities = new List<dynamic>(DTO2Service.GetListOfDTO2());
```

or just populate the initially created instance

```
if(serviceType == "1")
    entities.AddRange(DTO1Service.GetListOfDTO1());
else if (serviceType == "2")
    entities.AddRange(DTO2Service.GetListOfDTO2());
```

I personally prefer the second option as you have already initialized the variable and would just be populating it instead of creating an instance just to reassign it after.

Comment: hi, you are correct im casting it wrong. i just want to know if @shree.pat18 solution is better to choose for the correct asnwers

Comment: Of the three options provided, my second suggestion applies best to the provided example.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comment on the question, I am under the impression that OP needed something like that:

```
public interface IAmDTO {

    int Id { get; set; }

    string Name { get; set; }
}

public class DTO1 : IAmDTO {

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class DTO2 : IAmDTO {

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class DTO1Service {

    public static List<DTO1> GetListOfDTO1() =>
        new List<DTO1>
        {
        new DTO1 { Id = 1, Name = "DTO 1" },
        new DTO1 { Id = 2, Name = "DTO 2" },
        };
}

public class DTO2Service {

    public static List<DTO2> GetListOfDTO2() =>
        new List<DTO2>
        {
        new DTO2 { Id = 1, Name = "DTO 1" },
        new DTO2 { Id = 2, Name = "DTO 2" },
        };
}
}

public static class DTOExtensions {

public static void DtoHelper(this IEnumerable<IAmDTO> dtoS) {
    foreach(var dto in dtoS) {
        //DO SOMETHING WITH
        var id = dto.Id;
        var name = dto.Name;
    }

}
```

}